# MySQL80 Service on local computer started and the stopped. How to solve?

Tags: mysql, windows

I'm receiving this error of `MYSQL80 service on local computer started and stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs.` when I try to start my MySQL server from the services.msc

I already run `mysqld --install` and `mysqld --initialize`. Already tried to change the properties of the service to local system account. I checked `my.ini` file, it is in Program Data folder, the Uploads folder exists as well. I also checked the `.err` file but nothing is helpful there, the last line is something like `'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode.` that I don't really know what it means and google didn't help.

I don't know what else to try, I tried pretty much everything that I found.

This is my path to executable, do you think this should point to `my.ini` file? If so, how do I change that?

[image: Path to executable]

Also, there is another MySQL service on the list which I can start, but it's empty, my database is on the MySQL80 server (the one that I cannot start):

[image: Servers list]

Any idea?

Comment: Did you try stopping MySQL service and start MySQL80?
Do you have skype installed in your PC?

Comment: In `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini` file, open it in notepad and save with `ANSI` char.

Comment: In the _RC_ 8.04 there was a bug in which the service option in the install config was unchecked, yet the service ran. After intelligently removing the contents of the data directory in an attempt to reset users, the service would start, and immediately end with no error, presumably as it couldn't find any config/data files. Upgrading to 8.035 fixed it all.

Answer (score 2):

If using version 8 and you edit the my.ini I found that Notepad is putting 3 hex characters at the beginning of the my.ini file. EF BB BF. Deleting the 3 characters from the beginning of the file in a hex editor fixes the problem.

In version 8 they are accidentally putting Unicode characters in the ini file. This is causing Notepad to save the file with Byte order mark characters.

The following line in the file is the culprit "The line # range from 1 to 2^32 − 1. “Unique” means that each ID must be different." has 3 Unicode characters. This is causing notepad to append the byte order mark to the text file.

The other solution is to replace the my.ini file if you have a backup.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the password you enter is valid and still it's showing a login error.
I had the same issue just to allow the table to CSV export. I made some changes in my.ini and the service mysql80 never started.. after searching everywhere I came to the conclusion that we need to uninstall the MySQL server (Just server) and reinstall it.
Don't worry your databases will be safe just uninstall MySQL server "Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features" and reinstall MySQL server. MySQL installer-> add->mysql server 8.X.X, and try login again.
Hope this help just worked like magic for me.

Comment: The question was not about login issue, but mysql service failing to start.

Comment: I would never just assume data will be safe, good idea to back up the tablespace 'data' directory(s)

Answer (score -2):

Stop the service `mysql` and start the services `mysql80`.

That's what I did and worked.